# (How) can a handler set the return value of signal function?

Tags: common-lisp

From SBCL's documentation, we can learn:

> Invokes the signal facility on a condition formed from DATUM and
> ARGUMENTS. If the condition is not handled, NIL is returned.

It does not elaborate on what `signal` returns in case of a handled condition.
So, I assumed (guessed), that the handler can somehow determine the return value of the signal function:

```
(defun countdown (&optional
            (start-value 10)
            (fail-value 1))
  (loop
    repeat start-value
    for i from 0
    collecting
    (if (= i fail-value)
        (signal "fail-value (~D) hit!" i)
        i)))
(defun countdown-progress-indicator-style (&optional
                         (start-value 10)
                         (fail-value 1))
  (handler-bind
      ((simple-condition (lambda (c)
               (format t "fail (~A)~%" c)
               fail-value))) ;; <--- I hoped the return value of the handler is returned by signal!
    (countdown start-value fail-value)))
```

But: even if handled, `signal` returns `nil`.

> (countdown-progress-indicator-style)
> fail (fail-value (1) hit!)
> (0 NIL 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

Hence, my question, if there is a function or mechanism I missed, which allows the handler to influence `signal`'s return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [CLHS](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/09_a.htm) explains it nicely:  in order to handle a condition, you need to transfer control.  This can be all kinds of things, but the *usual* way is to invoke a restart.

```lisp
(defun countdown (&optional
                   (start-value 10)
                   (fail-value 1))
  (loop repeat start-value
        for i from 0
        collecting
        (restart-case
            (if (= i fail-value)
                (signal "fail-value (~D) hit!" i)
                i)
          (use-fail-value (fv)
            fv))))

(defun countdown-progress-indicator-style (&optional
                                            (start-value 10)
                                            (fail-value 1))
  (handler-bind
      ((simple-condition (lambda (c)
                           (format t "Handling simple condition~%")
                           (apply #'format t
                                  (simple-condition-format-control c)
                                  (simple-condition-format-arguments c))
                           (invoke-restart 'use-fail-value
                                           (first (simple-condition-format-arguments c))))))
    (countdown start-value fail-value)))
```

This somewhat abuses `simple-condition`s arguments; you should probably make your own condition, which takes the value explicitly.

Comment: I did not get as of yet, that restart-case is intended to be used at the source of a condition. I do not think that the CLHS explains much "nicely". It is like a maze and you never get the full story in one place. Them referring to a paper which is not publicly available does not help the matter, either. And examples I found always go on tangents, like defining custom condition types, which, IMHO is just a distraction.

Comment: @BitTickler If you search for 'Exceptional Situations in Lisp' the first several hits are that paper, one of them being on KMP's (its author's) own site.  It is, in fact, publicly available.

Comment: Restarts can be established anywhere on the stack between the handler and the source of the condition.  You can also have multiple.  For example, in a CSV parser library, you can have restarts at different levels for a parsing error: use a value for a cell, use a value for a line, skip line, skip file.  The user code using the library would have a handler that chooses, possibly after asking the user of the software.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to put it is that you made a nice discovery. You can signal an exceptional situation, have it processed by `handler-bind`, and carry on execution (or choose not to by using restarts).

With `handler-case`, you can exit early with a return value.

```lisp
(handler-case (countdown 3)
   (simple-condition ()
      (print :exiting-now!)))

;;=>
:EXITING-NOW! 
:EXITING-NOW!
```

> If a condition is signaled for which there is an appropriate error-clause during the execution of expression and if there is no intervening handler for a condition of that type, then control is transferred to the body of the relevant error-clause.

http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_hand_1.htm#handler-case